# Performance and Diagnostics Hub missing from Visual Studio Community Edition 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, ide

According to [this page](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dorischen/archive/2014/11/12/q-amp-a-on-visual-studio-community-2013-and-2015-preview.aspx), "Visual Studio Community 2013 shares the same features as Visual Studio Professional 2013."

According to [this page](http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/compare-visual-studio-products-vs.aspx#), Visual Studio Pro includes the Performance and Diagnostics Hub.

Based on those links, the Performance and Diagnostics Hub should be available in my copy of Visual Studio Community 2013, but it isn't. Was this moved to a somewhere else in the IDE or has it been removed since Community Edition was released?

Comment: I'm seeing the same issue, in VS2013 Premium with Update4, I'm currently doing a modify install to see if it's in one of the modules I hadn't already installed.